# Problem with dtypes() after dropping marked values

Tags: python, excel

I have a dataframe with marked values ?'s:

```
**A1  A2  A3    A4**
  =================  
  a   1   2.67  2.3  
  b   ?   9.00  3.2  
  aa  0   3.33  4.4  
  a   0   ?     1.5
```

and using dtypes() to check the type:

```
A1: object  
A2: object  
A3: object  
A4: float64
```

Now I replace the `?` marked values with `np.NaN` and then using `dropna()` to clean the marked values.
The dataframe now looks like:

```
**A1  A2  A3    A4**
  =================  
  a   1   2.67  2.3  
  aa  0   3.33  4.4
```

and if i use `dtypes()` again to check, the results are still the same:

```
A1: object  
A2: object  
A3: object  
A4: float64
```

While I expect that the data type of A2 should be `Bool` and data type of A3 should be `float64`.

Any help or explanation for this ?

Answer (score 0):

These are string representations of the numbers, perhaps apply `pd.to_numeric`:

```
df.apply(pd.to_numeric)
```

After the new df

Comment: it shows the error "Unable to parse string "a" at position 0". It seems like the whole dataset will be changed to numerical type. Although the result i expect is: A1: object, A2: Bool, A3 and A4: float64